# Google Calendar ignoring timeZone parameter

Tags: google-api, timezone, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add the stock moon phases calendar to a web site via the calendar API. But... the data always comes back in UTC. E.g., this get request
    `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/ht3jlfaac5lfd6263ulfh4tql8%40group.calendar.google.com/events?orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2017-10-31T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&timeMax=2018-01-07T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&maxResults=10&timeZone=America%2FNew_York&key={API_KEY}`

gets me this response

```
    {
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32o9hktouumte0g\"",
 "summary": "Phases of the Moon",
 "updated": "2017-11-07T18:33:19.000Z",
 "timeZone": "UTC",
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "EiIKF21vb25waGFzZSsxNTA5NzcyOTgwMDAwGICAm7jOo9cC",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"2453932800000000\"",
   "id": "moonphase+1509772980000",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=bW9vbnBoYXNlKzE1MDk3NzI5ODAwMDAgaHQzamxmYWFjNWxmZDYyNjN1bGZoNHRxbDhAZw&ctz=America/New_York",
   "created": "2008-11-18T00:00:00.000Z",
   "updated": "2008-11-18T00:00:00.000Z",
   "summary": "Full moon 5:23am",
   "creator": {
    "email": "ht3jlfaac5lfd6263ulfh4tql8@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Phases of the Moon",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "ht3jlfaac5lfd6263ulfh4tql8@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Phases of the Moon",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "date": "2017-11-04"
   },
   "end": {
    "date": "2017-11-05"
   },
   "visibility": "public",
   "iCalUID": "moonphase+1509772980000@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "gadget": {
    "title": "Full moon 5:23am",
    "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/calendar/images/moon/full-moon.gif"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And you'll notice the timeZone is listed as UTC and the summary and description fields have text representations of the times which are in UTC. It seems to have sort-of recognized my timeZone in that htmlLink field shows the zone as America/New_York.

You might be thinking that's just the way it works, except....

If you go to the Google test page for this API at

```
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
```

And plug in those parameters, the calendar data comes back in zone America/New_York.

Any ideas on what the magic is to make that happen?

Comment: Interestingly, I think the Google test page is actually ignoring the time zone, or rather just passing it through. If I put some other timeZone value, e.g., America/Los_Angeles, the htmlLink field uses ctz=America/Los_Angeles, but the rest of the output is the same, i.e., the summary string on each event, the timeZone of the entire response, etc., are unchanged. I'd guess I hit a server running in my zone.